# Android error on activity start

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't know why I get an error on the name FirstActivity?

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onStart();
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello, Android");
    setContentView(tv);
           }
        }
```

Comment: You should not be calling super.onstart' framework will take care of that

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to know what error you've got, but I think the problem is the

```
super.onStart();
```

line in your code.

`onStart()` would be called by the activity after `onCreate()` and you dont have to call it by yourself ([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Remove **super.onStart()** from your code.

And this link will help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello, Android");
    setContentView(tv);
  }
}
```

You do not need to call super.onStart() in onCreate().

Other than that, your error could be because you have a mismatched constructor somewhere (Activities to need need constructors), or because your .java file has a different name.